# Disable check for using 'kotlin' package in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, kotlin

When I try to `gradlew build` my project, I receive an error message from the `compileKotlin` task:

```
F:\IdeaProjects\walp.tinykotlintest>gradlew build
:compileKotlin
...
Only the Kotlin standard library is allowed to use the 'kotlin' package
...

BUILD FAILED 

Total time: 6.214 secs
```

This happens because I've declared a class in a package that starts with: `kotlin`...

**Is there a way to dissable this check by configuring my `build.gradle` script?**

EDIT: I know for sure this is possible if I compile with the bare kotlin compiler...[here is an example](https://github.com/ericytsang/question.compilekotlinpackage) of using the kotlin compiler to compile a class in the kotlin package...So I think there should to be a way to do it in gradle too!....I hope...

## What I've tried so far:

1. I tried to configure the `gradle.build` by configuring the KotlinCompile task:

   ```
   import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

   tasks.withType(KotlinCompile) {
       it.kotlinOptions.allowKotlinPackage = true
   }
   ```

   The gradle script runs fine with these changes...[but it seems like this is getting ignored](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.0.3/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin-core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/tasks/Tasks.kt#L196-L205)...and I still encounter the error.
2. I tried to subclass the `KotlinCompile` class and override its [`beforeCompileHook()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.0.3/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin-core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/tasks/Tasks.kt#L62-L63) and replace the existing `compileKotlin` task with my version:

   ```
   import org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.K2JVMCompilerArguments
   import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

   class MyKotlinCompile extends KotlinCompile {
       @Override
       public void beforeCompileHook(K2JVMCompilerArguments args) {
           args.allowKotlinPackage = true
           throw new RuntimeException("HELLO") // added to see if hook is run
       }
   }

   tasks.create(name: "compileKotlin", type: MyKotlinCompile, overwrite: true)
   ```

   [Studying the source code...I was fairly certain this would work](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.0.3/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin-core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/tasks/Tasks.kt#L104-L114) but evidently it didn't. I tried with and without throwing the `RuntimeException` but I always get the following error when I tried to `gradle build` again:

   ```
   F:\IdeaProjects\walp.tinykotlintest>gradlew build --stacktrace
   :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE                                                        
   :compileJava UP-TO-DATE     
   :processResources UP-TO-DATE      
   :classes UP-TO-DATE      
   :jar UP-TO-DATE      
   :sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE      
   :assemble UP-TO-DATE      
   :compileTestKotlin FAILED                                                  

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':compileTestKotlin'.
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

   * Try:        
   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

   * Exception is:
   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestKotlin'.
           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
                           .
                           .
                           .
           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile$populateTargetSpecificArgs$2.invoke(Tasks.kt:215)
           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.populateTargetSpecificArgs(Tasks.kt:222)
           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.populateTargetSpecificArgs(Tasks.kt:148)
           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:105)
           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
           ... 60 more
   ```

*I probably shouldn't be doing this anyways...but I really want to try it out.*

thank you!

Comment: what is the full name of the package?

Comment: `kotlin.jvm.internal` ....haha :x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Kotlin standard library is incompatible with the JVM that you're using, it sounds like what you should actually do is fork Kotlin, make the changes required for compatibility with your JVM, and then use the standard [Maven build script](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/pom.xml) to build your fork. The script already provides the option to allow compiling files in the `kotlin` package.

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with Gradle. The Kotlin compiler won't compile code in a `kotlin` package unless you are developing the Kotlin itself.

This was done for the same reason you can't write code in a `java` package.

Comment: Hi voddan, thanks for the answer..but I don't think it's accurate. The currently available kotlin compiler provides the option `-Xallow-kotlin-package` which disables the kotlin package check (if you have the kotlin compiler, run this command: `kotlinc -X` to see a description of the option). also, the java compiler doesn't prevent us from declaring classes in the `java` package. I've just tested compiling a class in the kotlin package with the kotlin compiler and compiling java with the java package just now to make sure

Comment: Hm, interesting, because I checked that too for java and got `java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.test1`

Comment: I know about the compiler option, but you absolutely should NOT use it unless you are on the Kotlin development team. Classes in the kotlin package some cases compile differently from all others. DO  NOT  USE THIS  FOR  DEVELOPMENT!

Comment: You're right. That exception occurs when trying to run a main function in the java package..but it is possible to declare a class in a java package and then use the class from another package...The reason why I'm trying to declare things in the kotlin package is because I'm programing for a third party JVM meant for a specific embedded system...this JVM's "standard library" is doesn't have all the classes that exist in a standard JVM...which makes including kotlin's runtime library get unresolved symbols...so I wanted to try and see if I could fix it although I think I'll most likely fail

Comment: I think this is a problem worth discussing with the Kotlin team. File an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT and they will help with a workaround.

Comment: Hi voddan, thanks for the suggestion. I've finally filed an issue:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13391

Comment: @LemuelAdane how supporting a new platform configuration is a bug to you?